# Animate a cell while removing Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4

I am developing an app where i am using some tableView cell. I am performing drag and drop operations on cell and i want to remove a cell at destination location. And i am successfully doing that. But before removing that cell i want to animate that cell. How can i do that. Below is the method from which i am performing this operation.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    let movedCell = self.colorArray[destinationIndexPath.row]

    self.colorArray.remove(at: destinationIndexPath.row)

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

i want to perform someAnimation on that movedCell.
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default system of animating `tableview` during remove.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
   self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [destinationIndexPath], with: .left)
    let movedCell = self.colorArray[destinationIndexPath.row]
    self.colorArray.remove(at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: When i am using this, Its crashing my app saying that 

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (10) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).`

Do you have any idea, why this is happening

Comment: I just updated my answer. Please try again. Another one `destinationIndexPath ` is the actual index path you try to remove?